# Biggest rate of growth of a sequence in $ℓ^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

$ℓ^2$ is the space of complex sequences $u_n$ such that $\sum |u_n|^2$ converges.

I'm wondering if there are asymptotic results known about such sequences. We have trivially $u_n=o(1)$.

Are better bounds known ? What if other constraints are added (monotonocity e.g) ?

I would say $u_n=O(\frac{1}{n})$ holds, but no counter-example comes to mind.

Comment: Take a sequence that is everywhere zero except for $n=2^m$. For such $n$s, take $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Here we have a counter-example.

Comment: What about :
$$u_n=\cases{ n^{-1} & \text{if } n \text{ is not a power of $p$ } 
\cr n^{-1/p} & \text{if } n \text{ is a power of $p$}}$$

The sum $\sum |u_n|^2$ converges. But, $u_n=\mathcal{O}(n^{-1/p})$ This is true for any $p\in\mathbb N$. So $\mathcal{O}(n^{-\varepsilon})$ sequences can be in $ℓ^2$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: There is the well-known $\limsup_n|u_n|^{2/n}\leq1$. On the other hand, there is not going to be a "biggest" due to the [lack of slowest converging series](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/452074/26489).