# On decreasing sequences $(a_n)_n$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

As an exercise for my math class, I have to find the widest possible choices of sequences $(a_n)_n$ such that $(a_n)_n$ is a nonnegative decreasing and the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$$ diverges.

I was thinking about $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$, so that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$
is the harmonic series which diverges.

Could someone please help me with more exmples?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the examples supposed to satisfy specific constraints?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "widest possible choices of sequences"?

Comment: @AlannRosas nothing more than the fact that $a_n$ has to be a decreasing sequence (I guess in the next class some we will add some more binding conditions, but that's all so far).

Comment: Maybe it's a requirement the terms of the sequence to be non-negative, otherwise it's too easy.

Comment: Note that for every diverging series $\sum a_n$ there is a “more slowly” diverging series $\sum b_n$ with $b_n/a_n \to 0$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452053/42969

Comment: @5xum I mean "as many examples as possible".

Comment: Typical examples are $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$,$\sum \frac{1}{n \ln (n) \ln(\ln(n))}$, ...

Comment: @User1010 What does "as many as possible" mean, mathematically?

Comment: @MartinR thank you!

Comment: How about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin \frac 1n$?

Comment: @5xum "What does "as many as possible" mean, mathematically?" Maybe it means the  limit as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(1)$ Take for example

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^\alpha}$$

where $\alpha$ is a fixed number in the interval $(0,1)$

Give different values for $\alpha$ and you will get different divergent series.

$(2)$ More examples:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln(n)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2(n)}$$

All these are divergent.

$(3)$ In general if $f(n)$ is a strictly increasing function which grows more
slowly than $g(n) = n$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}$$  is also divergent.

$(4)$ Other interesting examples would be:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} {\sin(n)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} {\cos(n)}$$

They are also divergent. But their terms are **not** all non-negative.

Comment: Something different from $sum\frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$?

Comment: I added a few more examples.

Comment: $\sin(n)$ is neither non-negative nor decreasing.

Comment: @MartinR I know. I didn't say it was.

Comment: But that is what the question asks for.

Comment: @MartinR It asks for that after I mentioned it, and the OP changed the question.

Comment: @MartinR I don't claim that. Maybe you misread something.

Comment: Indeed, I misread.

Comment: @MartinR I put a "But"  there and some highlighting to avoid others misreading.