# Finding much smaller series $c_n$ than a non-increasing $a_n$ , with divergent sum, whose sum is also divergent.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

While proving a theorem, the Professor stated the following lemma without proof:
Let $a_n$ be a non increasing positive series, such that $\sum_n a_n=\infty$
One can find a positive series $c_n$ such that  $\sum_n c_n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{c_n}{a_{bn}}=0$  for all integer $b>0$

I tried to use the fact that given a series as $a_n$, one can show that $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_n}=\infty$ when $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$
But it only proves the case of $b=1$.
A further attempt was to assume that $a_n<1/n$ as for $a_n=1/n$ we can choose $c_n=\frac{1}{n\log{n}}$, and also noticisng that in that case ($a_n<1/n$) $S_{n^2} \le 2S_n$ and thus we also have  $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_{n^2}}=\infty$, but I could not not prove from here the desired limit.

Comment: Related to this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452053/is-there-a-slowest-rate-of-divergence-of-a-series

Answer (score 1):

Your idea still works even when $b>1$. That's because your sequence $a_n$ consists of positive terms, thus $0\leq\sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_{bn}}\leq \sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_{n}} $. The righhand side converges to zero, so by the squeeze theorem $\sum_n \frac{a_n}{S_{bn}}$ converges to zero as well.