# If the partial sums of a sequence converges, what do we know about the convergence of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, reference-request, asymptotics

If for a sequence $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\in\mathbb{R} $$ what do we know about the convergence of $a$? It is well known that $a$ converges to $0$, but for example how fast does it converge? In general, I presume, we do not know much since with the Alternating Series Test you can construct sequences who go at any speed to $0$, but the alternating series still converges.

However, if the convergence is absolute (EDIT: it has been pointed out that this is not enough, the sequence has to be decreasing in magnitude as well), the sequence has to go to $0$ faster than $1/n$ and I suspect it either is asymptotically equivalent to $n^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha<-1$ or it goes to $0$ much faster than any such sequence. Does anyone know if my intuition is correct or false?

Is there literature on this, some cool results? Any suggestions and enlightenments on this are much appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/452074/42969. For every converging series you can find another one whose terms are much larger and it is still converging.

Comment: Wow, that's neat. So $na_n\to 0$ is the best we can say in the absolute convergence case, right?

Comment: @ManateePink What do you mean by that comment? Please be more precise

Comment: @ManateePink: $n a_n \to 0$ holds for a converging series with *decreasing elements* but not in general.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson, up until now I was pretty sure I proved to myself that if the partial sums converge absolutely then the sequence goes to $0$ faster than $1/n$, meaning $na_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ as I mentioned in the question. However, with the recent comments I am not so sure anymore. However, with Martin R.'s comment, it seemed to me that essentially $1/n$ was the only sequence we could make conclusions about with regards to the asymptotic behavior of $a$. So, that's why I wrote the best we could do.

Comment: @Martin R., but I thought since absolutely convergent series are unconditionally convergent, we could always reorder the sequence to a decreasing one?

Comment: You talk about $na_n$.  When you reorder $a_n$ (call it $b_n$), the values of $na_n$ are not the same as the values of $nb_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is incorrect in the case of absolute convergence, you can consider logarithmic corrections to $1/n$ to make the series converge or diverge. So there is no $\alpha<-1$, and moreover there is no specific cutoff point for the growth rate either (rather, an infinite sequence of functions that straddle divergence and convergence and which become "closer" to one another in some sense, although of course always having a ratio which diverges).

Comment: For example, $\sum 1/(n (\log n)^2)$ converges.

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah, I didn't think about logarithmic multipliers. Thanks for the concrete example @GEdgar. So $na_n\to 0$ is the best we can say?

Comment: For your next assignment:  Find an example with $a_n > 0$, where $\sum a_n$ converges, but $n a_n$ does not go to zero.

Comment: @GEdgar, that comment concerns me, I was pretty sure I recently proved that result recently to myself, but looks like I have to post another question to see where I went wrong...

Comment: Hint: $a_n$ does not need to be monotonically decreasing.  It could have rare terms that are relatively large.

Comment: You mean like, $a_n=1/n^2$, but every square $n$ $a_n=1/n$?