Can we characterize (absolute) convergence of series with big O notation?
More specifically: Is there a function $f$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if $|a_n| = O(f(n))$? Or with another Landau symbol like $o(f(n))$?
Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^\alpha}$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ converges if and only if $\alpha > 1$, we know that $|a_n| = o(1/n)$ is necessary and $|a_n| = O(1/n^{1+\varepsilon})$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ is sufficient for the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.
But of course there are cases, where none of these two conditions apply, like $a_n = \frac{1}{n \log n}$.
Since $\int \frac{1}{x \log x} dx = \log(\log(x)) + C$, we have $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \log n} = \infty$ and get the necessary condition $|a_n| = o(1/(n \log n))$.
The integral $\int 1/({x (\log x)^{1+\varepsilon}}) dx = -1/(\varepsilon \log(x)^\varepsilon)$ leads to the sufficient condition $|a_n| = O(1/(n (\log n)^{1+\varepsilon}))$.
We could go on with $\int \frac{1}{x \log(x) \log(\log(x))} dx = \log(\log(\log(x))) + C$ and $\int \frac{1}{x \log(x) \log(\log(x)) \log(\log(\log(x)))} dx = \log(\log(\log(\log(x)))) + C$ etc. to get necessary conditions like $|a_n| = o(1/(\log(x) \log(\log(x)) \log(\log(\log(x)))))$.
So maybe in the limit
$$ f(x) = \frac 1 x \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\log^k(x)} $$
could be a candidate such that $|a_n| = o(f(n))$ is necessary and sufficient for the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, but is this true? Does the product converge? Or can this $\log$-$\log$-$\log$-thing never lead to the answer since there are also functions like the iterated logarithm $\log^*(x)$ that grow slower than any iteration $\log^k(x)$? Could we maybe proof, that there is no single function $f$ for a big O notation charaterization of series convergence?

I have a feeling Hardy's Pure Mathematics considers this sort of thing.

This seems related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/452053/42969 – For every converging series you can find another converging series with much larger terms, and for every diverging series you can find another diverging series with much smaller terms.

The function $f(x)$ is not defined for any real number: for $\log x$ you need $x>0$, for $\log\log x$ you need $x>1$, for $\log\log\log x$ you need $x>e$, for $\log\log\log\log x$ you need $x>e^e$, ...

@jjagmath Oh yes, this $f$ is nowhere defined...

@MartinR Thank you! The theorem in the answer should imply, that no such $f$ can exist.
